# In C, how do you scan only half of a line of input?

Tags: c

Simple question (I think), in C, I was able to scan in an entire line using:

```
fgets(line, MAX, input);
printf("%s\n", line);
```

Where it would, for example, print "Please cut me in half", how do I only get "me in half", including white spaces.

Comment: Half in what sense? String length divided by two? The last half of the tokenised string split by a space delimiter?

Comment: You can make the line as a buffer and abandon the front part.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, as far as cutting in half, I was using that as an example and I found that using strlen cuts the number of characters in half. Specific to my needs, I need to only cut out the first word. Also, I do not need tokens, I need the entire line, spaces and all after the first word(excluding space after first word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not know where the middle is until you scan the whole line. But you can scan the entire line, and then print only the second half, like this:

```
printf("%s\n", line+strlen(line)/2);
```

This is how the above code works: `strlen` determines the length of the entire string (21), then we divide it in half using integer division (10), add it to the pointer to the beginning of the line, and pass the result to `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

You scan whole line into char array and then you take from this char array only characters that you need.

What you should be really looking for is: [Parsing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2695114/1168156)

Check [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First half:

```
printf("%.*s\n", strlen(line) / 2, line);
```

or first half but modifying `line` array:

```
line[strlen(line) / 2] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", line);
```

Second half:

```
printf("%s\n", line + strlen(line) / 2);
```

Comment: I think you wanted `strlen(line) / 2` ;).

Answer (score 1):

`line` is an array, so you can use pointer arithmetic:

```
printf("%s\n", line + (strlen (line)/2));
```

You "move" the beginning point from which string is displayed.

Comment: @ralu: That's exactly what the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

strlen(line) should give you the length of the line, then you can use a char array of half that length, iterate over the original line that many times, and copy character by character?

Don't forget to end the new array with a '\0'. :) Hope that works?